# NUnit3.2 running test cases in parallel

Tags: parallel-processing, nunit

Have anyone tried running **test cases** in parallel using NUnit 3.2? I have few thousand test cases written using NUnit(2.6.3) and i want to run them in parallel. Since NUnit 2.6.3 don't have the feature to run test cases in parallel, I thought of switching to NUnit 3.2. When i read the documentation, it says it support running **test fixtures in parallel not test cases**. Some web site says NUnit 3.2 support running test cases in parallel. I'm confused. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

NUnit 3 intends to allow running all kinds of tests (suites, fixtures, simple test methods, test cases) in parallel.

As far as NUnit 3.2, we only run tests in parallell down to the fixture level. The test methods/cases under the fixture run one at a time. So long as you have a relatively large number of fixtures, this gives an equivalent performance increase to running the methods in parallel. However, in the extreme, for example with a single fixture and 1000 methods, you will see no improvement.

No promises, but I imagine we'll be running test cases in parallel for 3.4.

Comment: Charlie, why **parallel running test case** feature exist in 3.0 not in 3.2? why the feature is removed in 3.2?

Comment: Test cases can't be run in parallel in either 3.0 or 3.2.